# Excel file editing through C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to open the excel file in C# and replace some values and add some new data to it and save it as a new file. I can read the excel file using OleDb, it gives me only data and it does not give the Font, Color, ColSpan, RowSpan etc of each cell. I can use ClosedXML library to create the excel file with required font, color etc. I want to know, is there any way through which I can do similar to model binding in razor views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To use Excel library, you need `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` (found in `Reference Manager -> Extensions`)

Comment: @JohnyL, I'd recommend something other than the Microsoft interop library.  It's too easy to end up with a bunch of Excel processes running in the background because you didn't clean up your code exactly right.  I'd recommend freely available libraries like EPPlus, or NPOI.  OP, check this out https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=excel